# What is the number of spanning trees of a labelled complete graph on $n$ vertices such that each vertex of the tree has degree at most $3$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations, trees

> How many distinct subgraphs of a complete graph of $n$ labelled vertices are there such that the subgraph is a spanning tree connecting all the vertices and the degree of no vertex is more than $3$?

If $a_n$ denotes the number of such subgraphs, then for small values of $n$, by bruteforcing we have

- $a_1=1$,
- $a_2=1$,
- $a_3=3$,
- $a_4=16$,
- $a_5=120$.

How to find $a_n$ without bruteforcing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of spanning trees in the complete graph $K_n$ with a degree $d_i$ specified for each vertex $i$ can be counted using [Prüfer codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence#Other_applications.5B3.5D). The Prüfer code has $n-2$ slots, of which $d_i-1$ contain the label $i$, so the number of Prüfer codes corresponding to the specified degrees is the multinomial coefficient

$$
\binom{n-2}{d_1-1,\,d_2-1,\,\dots,\,d_n-1}=\frac{(n-2)!}{(d_1-1)!(d_2-1)!\cdots(d_{n}-1)!}\;.
$$

We want all degrees to be $1$, $2$ or $3$. Denote the number of vertices with degree $k$ by $n_k$. Then we can choose groups of $n_1$, $n_2$ and $n_3$ vertices out of $n$, which yields another multinomial coefficient, and in the coefficient above the factorials are all $1$ or $2$ and yield a factor of $2^{n_3}$ in the denominator. Thus the number of trees is

$$
\binom n{n_1,n_2,n_3}\frac{(n-2)!}{2^{n_3}}\;.
$$

Since we have $n$ vertices, we must have $n_1+n_2+n_3=n$, and since we have $n-1$ edges we must have $n_1+2n_2+3n_3=2n-2$. This allows us to express $n_1$ and $n_2$ in terms of $n_3$, namely $n_1=n_3+2$ and $n_2=n-2n_3-2$. Now we just have to sum over all possible values of $n_3$, i.e. the ones that make $n_2$ non-negative. The result is

$$
(n-2)!\sum_{n_3=0}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor-1}2^{-n_3}\frac{n!}{n_3!(n_3+2)!(n-2n_3-2)!}\;.
$$

This is [OEIS sequence A003692](https://oeis.org/A003692). That page gives a recurrence relation:

$$
(n+2)a_n = n(2n-1)a_{n-1} + (n-3)(n-1)na_{n-2}\;.
$$

(The indices are shifted with respect to the recurrence given at OEIS because the indexing of the OEIS sequence is off by $1$.)

Comment: Thanks. Excellent answer and very nice explanation.